# Is passing a Promise as a function argument considered a bad practise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have often asked myself about this, since it can lead to the obvious problem:

```
function someFunction (a, b) {
   return a + b
}
```

If `a` is a promise you would need to resolve it first:

```
async function someFunction (a, b) {
   a = await a
   return a + b
}
```

Leading to confusing on whether `a` is resolved or not...

Comment: No, it's not a bad practice, it happens all the time. For a good example look at expressJS callback functions, `app.use(async (req, res) => {})` if you  need to resolve async data in your function body that is fine. You can always await a promise, whether or not it's been resolved already before. It will just resolve ~instantly.

Comment: There also would be no confusion. Whether a is resolved or not, it will wait for it to resolve and then resolve the promise that was immediately returned after using await with the result of `a + b`. Consistency from start to finish.

Comment: Is this question opinion based? I'm sure there are different opinions on this topic. I think this question falls under _"Don't ask about... Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc."_ if there is no objective metric for _"bad practice"_

Comment: Remember that all `async` functions will synchronously return a promise. The moment you invoke `someFunction(a,b)` the `return a + b` line will work and you will receive a pending promise which will only get fullfilled once the `a` promise resolves or rejects. This is basically how promises work.

Comment: It's a great idea, and as usual Typescript can help you make it super clear it's supported and it must be awaited.

Comment: @CalIrvine That express example you've given does not pass a promise, it passes a promise-returning function as a callback.

Comment: @Bergi you're right, I misunderstood the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, one should generally avoid passing promises to functions. Prefer waiting for the promise and passing only the result, i.e. do

```
somethingAsync().then(x => someFunction(x, y))
// or
someFunction(await somethingAsync(), y)
```

instead of

```
someFunction(somethingAsync(), y)
```

As you say, it's very confusing otherwise, especially when not using TypeScript to tell you when you have messed up. And the implementation of `someFunction` becomes much simpler when it is synchronous and doesn't have to deal with any asynchronous logic, which also makes it more universally useful.

Of course, there are exceptions to every rule, and they would be functions that are explicitly dedicated to handle asynchronous promise logic, like `Promise.resolve`, `Promise.all`, `Promise.race`, `.then()` etc. Sometimes you write similar helper functions yourself, e.g. for error-handling, and in those cases it might be acceptable to pass a promise. It's still unusual though.